# VBA paste new values in column B of sheet 1 to last empty cell of B in sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

**Think of my problem like this: cells `FS3:FS33` show customer receipts for customers in the restaurant seats `3 to 33` ( those are the only seats ) at the present time. As they leave their receipts leave the cells `FS3:FS33` and go to the bin. New customers come and go and as they come and go `FS3:FS33` fills downwards to the last column ( ie there will be no gaps and they will fill from `FS3` down ). Each receipt is unique and needs to be recorded and kept on the last empty row of another column on a different sheet in C:C.**

**This Q has been answered but I have one final problem with it not updating - see below**

the combination of this sub in a module

```
Sub hithere3()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Unique As Boolean

For Each Rng In Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("FS3:FS30") 'for each cell     in     your B1 to B30 range, sheet1
Unique = True 'we'll assume it's unique
Lastunique = Worksheets("TRADES").Range("C:C").Find("*",     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For i = 3 To Lastunique 'for each cell in the unique ID cache
    If Rng.Value = Worksheets("TRADES").Cells(i, 3).Value Then 'we       check    if it is equal
        Unique = False 'if yes, it is not unique
    End If
Next
If Unique Then Worksheets("TRADES").Cells(Lastunique + 1, 3) = Rng 'adds    if it is unique
Next
End Sub
```

with the loop check in a worksheet change events

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("FS3:FS33")) Is Nothing Then
'Do nothing '
Else
Call hithere3
End If
End Sub
```

works except it only updates when I select one of the cells in FS3:FS33

Can anyone suggest how this can be overcome?

SOLUTION

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
If Range("FS3:FS33") Is Nothing Then
'Do nothing'
Else
 Call hithere3
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: To me your spec and examples are confusing.  You start quoting column B then show examples using columns A and C.  How would values "disappear" from Sheet 2?  Your initial spec seems fairly straight forward:  Create a worksheet_Change module, in sheet 1 using intersect to detect changes in B1:B30, then loop through cells in sheet 2, column B checking if your new value exists, if not enter it in last populated cell in B2.  For ideas you could search on her for how to use intersect, how to loop through a range and how to find last cell in a column.

Comment: By "last empty cell in column **B**", do you mean cell **B1048576** if it is empty ??

Comment: Worksheet change events will run by themselves, no need to execute manually.

Comment: @Jonwhite please don't edit answers. If you have more information, please edit your question. If you have a new question arising from what you have received so far, please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding as an answer because comments wont let me format the code section properly.  Jon am assuming you are using the code above from user3819867, all you need to do to use the intersect is change the worksheet_change module to be

`Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B30")) Is Nothing Then 
    'Do nothing '
else
    Call ertdfgcvb
end if
End Sub`

edited to add that I dont really see a need to call a seperate procedure here.  Would put the procedure code directly in here as its quite small, plus makes it easier to read if you decide to tweak and use "target" instead

Comment: I have added an additional comment to my above answer.  Using Target potentially avoids looping your whole range, you can just query target.  Though please note that if a user pastes multiple values in B1:B30, target could still be a range, but would just be  range of the changed value.  Up to you if you think you need to cater for this scenario

Comment: Worksheet_Change modules run automatically when you change a value in that sheet ... as long as they are in the right place.
In the VBA editor, by default, in the left hand side the project explorer is shown.  Expand the Microsoft Excel Objects, find your sheet where you want this code to run and double click it.  This should open a code window for that sheet.  This is where you need to put the worksheet_change code

Comment: One way of checking what's happening is to use the vba editor and add a breakpoint at the start of the worksheet_change procedure and when the code halts, step through and see if it is going where you expect it to

Comment: No, the yellow line is where the code has errored and you are debugging.   A breakpoint you add before the code runs.  In your code window, click the vertical left side of the code window next to the line of code where you want the code to "break".   Then when your code executes it will stop at this point and jumpot to the code window.  At this point you can do lots of useful things like hover cursor over variables to see what they are.  But also on the "debugging" toolbar are options to step throiugh your code.  Click thiis to move the code on 1 line at a time and see where its going

Comment: In relation to your actual error, I am at work and dont have time to debug  user3819867's code.  But I would actually do it slightly differently, by using an aray to hold sheet 2's existing values and loop through the array, but also add checks for empty sheet etc

Comment: I think I need to change if intersect (target, range("FS3:FS33")) no change do nothing else change do something or somethign becasue it wont update unless I select that range :(

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple solution for you. If your datasets are relatively small, it will take no time to run it on each value input (Worksheet_Change event).

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Unique As Boolean

For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B30") 'for each cell in your B1 to B30 range, sheet1
    Unique = True 'we'll assume it's unique
    Lastunique = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For i = 1 To Lastunique 'for each cell in the unique ID cache
        If rng.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value Then 'we check if it is equal
            Unique = False 'if yes, it is not unique
        End If
    Next
    If Unique Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Lastunique + 1, 2) = rng 'adds if it is unique
Next
End Sub
```

The call will look like:

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call ertdfgcvb
End Sub
```

If you have larger datasets, you will have to refer to *Target* instead.

Comment: Checked the runtime with 30 to 10,315, it's 6 to 7 seconds on my computer. It might be too long for each data entry depending on your preferences.

Comment: If there are no values, then it finds nothing and cannot return appropriate row number either. Other than that check for typos in sheet name.

Comment: I made an amendment (merely runtime) and uploaded my [example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-773Ttgo1z6Z2ZrczZmV19JcTA/view?usp=sharing). It works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, it measures runtime too. Feel free to comment it out.

Comment: `If rng.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value` will change to `If rng.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 17).Value` since column Q is the 17th in order. Likewise, `If Unique Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Lastunique + 1, 2) = rng 'adds if it is unique` changes too.

Comment: I would still use intersect to limit your code to only run when the change is in B1:B30 `If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B30")) Is Nothing Then 'Do nothing
'else process the changed value
Else`

Comment: You can then use an OnError event but it would be much better if you would just add a header in column Q like "Unique IDs", then you wouldn't have to worry about this bug. Alternatively you could add the first ID manually, and it would run smoothly until you hit the c. 1,000,000 as the upper limit of this sub.

Comment: I am not going back to the basics. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` ; `Application.StatusBar = "Updating"`

Comment: sorry about that user3819867. Your code worked great but now it doesn't wan tto update according to marks workchange event